# Keeping track of one's academic record and achievements

Tags: cv, workflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tools make it easy to maintain (or avoid!) the N versions of your CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4903/what-tools-make-it-easy-to-maintain-or-avoid-the-n-versions-of-your-cv)

When writing a CV (applying for an academic position, workshop or a scholarship), it's important to include one's list of publications, conference talks and posters, awards, etc.

Moreover, the list need to be tailored to the respective scope (and with the appropriate fine-graining).

The question is, **is there a specific workflow (or software) to keep tracks of one's academic records, so that later it's easy to cherry-pick the relevant stuff?**

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4903/what-tools-make-it-easy-to-maintain-or-avoid-the-n-versions-of-your-cv

Comment: Your question seems to be very close to that linked by Zenon, could you please explain how is it different?

Comment: @CharlesMorisset I somehow missed that question, and mine should be closed (you are right, it's too similar).

Answer (score 2):

[Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) and [Microsoft Academic Research](http://academic.research.microsoft.com) (also [DBLP](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/index.html) for computer science) collect a decent amount of one's publications (in particular Google Scholar).
If you are writing your CV in Latex/LyX, I would suggest finding/creating BIBTEX entries  for your papers then import the *.bib* file into your CV.

Answer (score 1):

On my website I keep a list of my academic achievements. This only includes journal publications, official reports, and conference proceedings though. When I need to make a list of my most relevant publications, I take a look at that page. A nice way to tracking your papers and such is to create a Google Scholar Citations page. This automatically looks for your publications and keeps record of the number of citations you receive.